# Alternate of if and foreach for Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Could there be a sophisticated LINQ for the following code.
My code is trying to prepare a dictionary of string(key), string(value), by first getting a list of objects from another dictionary and then looping over to that list of objects.

```
Dictionary<string, string> displayNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
List<DefDefaultDataSet.dbEnumsRow> enumList;

//allEnums dictionary: Key as string and value as List<DefDefaultDataSet.dbEnumsRow>
//enumID is a string object
if (allEnums.TryGetValue(enumID, out enumList))
{
   foreach (DefDefaultDataSet.dbEnumsRow row in enumList)
   {
       string enumValue = row.Value;
       //If already have enumvalue ,no need to add again
       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(enumValue) && !displayNames.ContainsKey(enumValue))
       {
            displayNames.Add(enumValue, FindResourceVal(row.ResourceKey, uniqueKey));
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Does your code work? If it does consider asking elsewhere as this site is for problems with code that doesn't work

Comment: Yes, it does work.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? It looks to me that you could use `ToDictionary()` but it's hard to reason about your code without seeing the entire thing (plus data).

Comment: @NateBarbettini This site is not here for code that works, please do not encourage questions like this. Also Vivek there is codereview.stackexchange.com for questions like this, but consider reader their help page first so you know you are asking an on topic question.

Comment: I will keep that in mind @TheLethalCoder

Comment: Nonsense. This site is for *answerable questions about code*. That code is allowed to be working code. If the question is "please review my code" then yes, there is a site for that, but this question is not "please review my code", it is "can this code be refactored into a query?" That's a perfectly sensible question to ask about working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the `if` statement, then filters using `Where` and create the dictionary using `ToDictinary`:

```
if (allEnums.TryGetValue(enumID, out enumList))
    displayNames = enumList.Where(e => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Value) && !displayNames.ContainsKey(e.Value))
                           .ToDictionary(k => k.ResourceKey, v => FindResourceVal(v.ResourceKey, uniqueKey));
```